# typescript generics class, method parameter and method return type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this function

```
function getCollection<T>(collectionType: T): Collection<T> {
  return new Collection<T>()
}
```

and in `Collection` class I have this

```
export class Collection<T> {
  public add (item: T) {
    // .. logic
  }
}
```

I have a user class defined like this

```
export class Student {

}
```

and when I attempt to do

```
getCollection(Student).add(new Student());
```

There is an error

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Student' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'typeof Student'.   Property 'prototype' is missing in type
> 'Student' but required in type 'typeof Student'.

Following works fine.

```
new Collection<Student>().add( new Student());
```

So what is wrong when the function returns generic collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is actually of type `typeof Student`. `Student` is an instance of the class, while `typeof Student` is the constructor. To get the instance type of a constructor, use the intuitively named `InstanceType` built-in:

```
public getCollection<T>(collectionType: T): Collection<InstanceType<T>> {
  return new Collection<InstanceType<T>>("some-arg1", "some-arg2")
}
```

But now you have to add a constraint which shouldn't be too much of a problem:

```
public getCollection<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(...
```

---

This should result in:

```
public getCollection<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(collectionType: T): Collection<InstanceType<T>> {
  return new Collection<InstanceType<T>>("some-arg1", "some-arg2")
}
```

Comment: Thank you @catgirlkelly -  with this it errors me with `TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.

Comment: @user3833308 Hence the second code block where I ask you to also add the generic constraint.

Comment: Edited answer to include the whole thing. Should've done that in the original lol

Comment: great and can you please explain the meaning of part after `extends` doesn't make sense

Comment: InstanceType only works with constructables. You add the constraint to make sure only constructors can be used.

Comment: what if my type (for example `Student`) is an `interface`?

Comment: @user3833308 Sorry, then it is not really possible. You can't get a "value" from just the generic type.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to the fact that the generic type is inferred from the parameter; meaning that `T` is not `Student` but it is actually `typeof Student`. Hence `return new Collection<T>` does not behave like `return new Collection<Student>` but is instead `return new Collection<typeof Student>`.

This can be fixed by actually assigning a type to the generic parameter:

`getCollection<Student>(Student)`

The above makes the use of the parameter redundant, hence `getCollection` can be refactored to the following:

```
getCollection<T>(): Collection<T> {
  return new Collection<T>("some-arg1", "some-arg2");
}
```

and be called as:

```
getCollection<Student>()
```

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEJKcBGASwgDsAeAFQD44BvAWACg5Ey0YoBXQ6ACg5QipAOYBGAFxxBwkQBppnWQCYpM0QEp6AX2aswXAEZIiCOCgAmFuHyIxgAWymUtjFqzgB6T3AB0vuCQIEVM9OF0mCOZQSFhEVAw4AGUYLgtgUng6KKYAMy5SQhJSOBFgGEoATzBgAHlcnDwCYjIqaj4EXHwisiqa5w0pRu6Wihp6MKhyrigS0mAAd2wu5uK2vgAiNAgHYABaFChxDYUtnf3DkWUNjQBuZhzvOGFc4Cg4XKgduBgAC2BzEcuLtMsxOqQOD9qnUGiseiUALylcp9GHDVZkPgpNIZGB3ZjMGDQ%20ro%20G%20SwWPjzJbY9KZPgaDTMJ5-IiYBZEPBwBbQADWz1ycEqEC45isP3%20cFRhOJsKaZIpWNSdLxBKYavyhVGyJgpNG60Gy3l%20vGblYU1Sszg1KNIzWNE2212ByOYhOcDOzsu13xkTVLOhz0waHKcEMlQlAPSADdgEEalAwex4ESanrinAkWVdXD9bTce1fangOmyOSrFTFsllbiGUz1UwgA).

Comment: Types are fine but how will you get the actual collection in code...

Comment: I'm not sure entirely sure what you mean?