# Custom utility types (generic types) for classes `IsClass` of TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, factory, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a `generic type` to make sure the first parameter to be a class. However, the factory function parameter cannot be replaced by a `generic type`.

The following upper parts were my attempts. The last part were a working example that directly write the `extends ...` which worked.

Why does it works inside a function, but not works as a `generic type` `IsClass`?

```js
class A {
  constructor() {

  }
}
class B {}
class C extends B {}

// ERRORS:

type IsClass<T extends new (...args: any) => InstanceType<T>> = T
type IsClass2<T> = T extends new (...args: any) => InstanceType<T>? T: never

type X = IsClass<A>
type Y = IsClass2<A>

function someFactoryError<T>(clx: IsClass<T>) {
  return new clx()
}

someFactoryError(A)

function someFactoryError2<T>(clx: IsClass2<T>) {
  return new clx()
}

someFactoryError2(A)

// WORKS:

function someFactoryWorks<T extends new (...args: any) => InstanceType<T>>(clx: T) {
  return new clx()
}

const a0 = someFactoryWorks(A)
const b0 = someFactoryWorks(B)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBBeBvU95gPYDsYBcAnAVzHy0IAoBKVUdeAX1GfGjngCFVXJYEAwvACmAD3zCcAEwTcUrUAHpF8AKIAldQHl1ALnoh8ATwAOw+AEkYA9jAA8AFRHjJM+DmEB3eJQB0-qEIAcxhdeCgcI1oAXgA+Szx8CLBhB1NhR1j46PgHUGMzS2tbACZM+BynMQlpBA9vPwDg0PDImPiLROTU9MyAflywjwA3YUIDAvMADQqim347RFj89PgATVmrebgypYMAM2IcMgBLXHgYLABbYQAxKDIKI1VCQgpMykhRMK3bTNo0CAMIRhPhiIQcO4vJgIKIaCwDJcbvdHoRnq8KJRENQDkdTuckXcHuQ0S83oQyg5Yp9YT9ivxKbEAQwQWCIVDvF94SAFCBCSiSejySUsTiQEoVAB1HQAaQAyvpxSBDsd8GdIfziU9JRQANb2KouWocnz+XyBEJhCJRCodLrHHpmTLUr5hBzMoHwVngyH1GFwsW87CJcIABlmmtRRh1hH1otAwYI8AARuGcpHBTG45xqEA)

#### Related:

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72137545/10100812)
- [TypeScript Handbook: Abstract Construct Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures)

Comment: You could try this:

```ts
type IsClass<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function someFactory<T>(clx: IsClass<T>) {
  return new clx();
}
```